# How to optimize blend by combining red and blue unsigned byte?

Tags: c++, optimization, rgb

I have this function for RGB blend. What I'm trying to do is put red and blue together to lessen the operations.

Here' the original code :

```
#define REDMASK (0xff0000)
#define GREENMASK (0x00ff00)
#define BLUEMASK (0x0000ff)
typedef unsigned int Pixel;
inline Pixel AddBlend( Pixel a_Color1, Pixel a_Color2 )
{
    const unsigned int r = (a_Color1 & REDMASK) + (a_Color2 & REDMASK);
    const unsigned int g = (a_Color1 & GREENMASK) + (a_Color2 & GREENMASK);
    const unsigned int b = (a_Color1 & BLUEMASK) + (a_Color2 & BLUEMASK);
    const unsigned r1 = (r & REDMASK) | (REDMASK * (r >> 24));
    const unsigned g1 = (g & GREENMASK) | (GREENMASK * (g >> 16));
    const unsigned b1 = (b & BLUEMASK) | (BLUEMASK * (b >> 8));
    return (r1 + g1 + b1);
}`
```

And here's what I got so far. My problem is right now is that the colours are not blending correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

```
typedef unsigned int Pixel;

inline Pixel AddBlend( Pixel a_Color1, Pixel a_Color2 ){
    const unsigned int rb = ( ( a_Color1 & 0xff00ff ) + ( a_Color2 & 0xff00ff ) );
    const unsigned int g = ( a_Color1 & GREENMASK ) + ( a_Color2 & GREENMASK );

    const unsigned rb1 = ( rb & 0xff00ff ) | ( 0xff00ff  * ( rb >> 8 ));    
    const unsigned g1 = (g & GREENMASK)  | (GREENMASK * (g >> 16));
     return (rb1 + g1);
}
```

Comment: Please specify what unexpected output you are getting from the function and for what inputs. One obvious problem is that there is no `return` statement in your second variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(REDMASK * (r >> 24))` type part in the original code handles clamping values that overflow.  This works with one color part, but not two.  You'll need to split that into two parts, one to handle the red overflow and one for the blue.  Handling the overflow for red can be done as in the original, but the blue overflow needs a little adjustment to ignore any of the red contribution.

```
BLUE_MASK * ((rb & 0x100) >> 8)
```

This results in

```
const unsigned rb1 = (rb & 0xff00ff) | (REDMASK * (r >> 24)) | (BLUE_MASK * ((rb & 0x100) >> 8));
```

Combining two colors like this works because there is a gap between red and blue that the overflow can occupy (the green bits).  If you tried this with red/green or green/blue the overflow for the part stored in the lower byte would collide with the value for the part stored in the higher byte.